# Flutter post request do not send parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, post

Here is my code, when I post the request, It just send http://10.0.2.2:43213/api/User/InsertNewUser as response.request and so do not put the body.
However, I need to send something like that http://10.0.2.2:43213/api/User/InsertNewUser?userName=test&userEmail=test@test.com&userPassword=test123
How can I post the parameters?

```
          Future<http.Response> postRequest () async {
              var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:43213/api/User/InsertNewUser');

              Map data = {
                'userName': 'test',
                'userEmail': 'test@test.com',
                'userPassword': 'test123'
              };
              //encode Map to JSON
              var body = json.encode(data);
              
              var response = await http.post(url,
                  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                  body: body
              );

              return response;

        }
```

EDIT: I found the solution.
There is no problem in the flutter post request part. Problem is in the server side. I send the parameters as body but my server is not waiting for a body. For the Asp.net, I needed to add [FromBody] in endpoint functions to accept and use paramaters from the body.

Comment: Are you sure that your server is expecting a JSON encoded body? It might be expecting a urlencoded form. As currently written it should be sending a JSON body. What makes you think it isn't reaching the server?

Comment: Parameters does not reach the server side. When I print the my response.request, it gives me only the url (http://10.0.2.2:43213/api/User/InsertNewUser) and do not put the parameters on the url to send the server side. However, I need to send something like that http://10.0.2.2:43213/api/User/InsertNewUser?userName=test&userEmail=test@test.com&userPassword=test123.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your comment that you do not want to JSON encode the parameters, so don't!

Change:

```
          //encode Map to JSON
          var body = json.encode(data);
          
          var response = await http.post(url,
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
              body: body
          );
```

to

```
          final response = await http.post(url, body: body);
```

`http` will then *form* encode your map and set the correct content type.

Adding the parameters to the URL (as you've done in the edit) would be used with a GET (rather than a POST). If you'd prefer that simply format your URL with the parameters as follows:

```
          final data = {
            'userName': 'test',
            'userEmail': 'test@test.com',
            'userPassword': 'test123'
          };

          final url = Uri.http('10.0.2.2:43213', '/api/User/InsertNewUser', data);
          
          final response = await http.get(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this;

```
  Future<http.Response> postRequest () async {

 var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:43213/api/User/InsertNewUser');

    Object myBody(){
      var theBody = jsonEncode(
              {
                'userName': 'test',
                'userEmail': 'test@test.com',
                'userPassword': 'test123'
              });
      return theBody;
    }

 var response = await http.post(url,
                  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                  body: myBody()
              );

              return response;
}
```